# error in ajax(jquery 1.8.3)

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have this code in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form_country').bind({
        'change' : function(){
            var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            if(value>=0){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{ path('fill_form_select') }}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        val : value
                    },
                    success : function(json){
                        var $formSelect2 = $('#form_city');
                        $formSelect2.attr('disabled',false);
                        $formSelect2.empty();

                        for(i=0; i<json.length; i++){
                            alert(json[i]);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('ERROR');
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
})
```

but when I load my page, I have alert('ERROR') why?

I think I have bug in this line: url: "{{ path('fill_form_select') }}"

How can I pass path with my router ?

Comment: what do you mean by this {{ path('fill_form_select') }}

Comment: Did you debug your code? and also, @MuraliPrasanth's question.

Comment: {{ path('fill_form_select') }} this is my path from routing in symfony2

Comment: yes, I have 404 error in this line {{ path('fill_form_select') }}